# Google Drive SDK Open with not working since 1 week

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We have created an application integrated with Google Drive. The application is executed from Google Drive using the "open with..." functionality https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open

The application has been working fine for more than one year, however suddenly since one week the "open with..." functionatliy is not working anymore.

The application works fine but it cannot be inovoked from Google Drive. When you try to run the app from the "open with..." menu, Google drive doens't launch the app (Previously it was working fine)

Note: It's not working in the new Drive interface although it was working some days ago. Using the Old Google Drive interface it still works perfectly fine.

For your information we have not changed anything in the application.

Does anyone know why it's not working as expected? Is it a bug of the New Drive interface or something has changed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any reference to Google App Engine in this Q -- can I just remove the google-app-engine tag if not relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to reply myself, becuase the issue has been fixed by Google. :-)